# FormData is not submitting checkbox value

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i am trying to submit form using FormData, all input types are working fine except checkbox. ajax is not posting if value is 1 or 0 from checkbox.

```
<form  id="update-form" method="PUT"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="Hello"> //fine
    <input type="checkbox" id="visa" name="visa" value="0"> //not posting    
    <button type="submit"  name="id" id="update-data" > UPDATE</button></form>
```

**Ajax:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e)  {
$('#update-data').on('click', function(e) {
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("update-form"));
    $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
            url: "subject/" + $('#update-data').attr("value"),
                headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
            data:formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,

            success: function (data) {
alert("Updated")
} },
}); }); });
```

**Controller:**

```
$teacher->update($request->all());
```

i tried to append FormData but it is also not working.

```
var checkbox = $("#update-form").find("input[type=checkbox]");
$.each(checkbox, function(key, val) {
    formData.append($(val).attr('name'), $("#visa").is(':checked'))

});
```

**Error:**

> local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect
>   integer value: 'true' for column `teacher_db`.`teachers`.`visa`

```
i want to post check box value 1 if it is checked and 0 if unchecked.
```

Comment: the logic of either 1 or 0 should be done on your backend... is that just all you want?

Comment: form is not submitting anything related to checkbox. all other input types are posting. why not check boxes?

Comment: @codervine i added controller.

Comment: Why force checkbox value in the input, try `<input type="checkbox" id="visa" name="visa">`

Comment: @BossCOTIGA if check or unchecked, always going 0 value.

Comment: If checkbox is unchecked, it would not be available in FormData. Are you saying it is also not available when it is checked?

Comment: yes either way it stays 0.

Answer (score 0):

on your controller, do this

```
$posted = Input::all();

if ( ! isset($posted['visa']){
    $posted['visa'] = 0; 
}else{
    $posted['visa'] = 1;
}
```

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: how to determine on frontend if it is check or unchecked? checkbox always returns 0

Comment: Where is `$data` coming from? You need to provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using form id as follows:

```js
$('#Yourformid').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('text',text.value);
  formData.append('visa',visa.checked);

  $.ajax({ #ajax code });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please always read the errors. The errors said:

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'true' for column teacher_db.teachers.visa
```

You just don't insert the correct value for the particular column (visa). Somehow the value coming from the Ajax for the `visa` checkbox is string `true` (not '1', or '0'). Since boolean using `integer`, you need to correctly cast that value (string) before inserting to the DB to `integer`.

```php
$teacher->update($request->merge([
    'visa' => in_array($request->input('visa'), ['true', 1, '1']),
])->all()));
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not understood your question correctly. I'm not sure what you want, little confused with the title `FormData is not submitting checkbox value`.